# dump JDBC Derby database to a SQL script

Tags: sql, netbeans, javadb, database-dump

I think this task should be obvious but I couldn't find how to do it.

I am going to create a Java DB database (Derby) that will later be copied from my computer to another computer through a SQL script. Can I create it using Netbeans' GUI and then export it (and if yes, how), or do I have to write the script myself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I found the answer. Everybody was talking about a program named `dblook` but I didn't know whether I have it or where it is in my Ubuntu box. So I do `locate dblook` in my system. The command is in the `bin` folder inside the installation directory of `javadb`

Here is some reference

http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javadb/10.5.1.1/tools/rtoolsdblookexamples.html